# How to assert if method doesnt have return statement without calling it in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, assert

Is there is a way to assert that a method has a return statement?
for example if I have this class:

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def method1(self):
        return 0
    def method2(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

when i create object from it `object1=class1()`, i would like to `something(object1.method2) == False`  to check wether it has return statement or not . and `assert(something(object1.method1))` should not return assertion error  while `method2` should.

was using `hasatrr()` and `callable()` but it still return `True` for `method2`

Comment: All Python functions return something unless they raise an exception even if the return is implicit (None)

Comment: is it possible to check wether the returns is None or not without calling the function ? @BrutusForcus

Answer (score 4):

You can get the definition of the function using `inspect` module and check if the function contains the word `return`:

```
from inspect import getsourcelines

def has_return(func):
    lines, _ = getsourcelines(func)
    return any(line.lstrip().startswith("return ") for line in lines) 

print(has_return(class1.method2)) # False
print(has_return(class1.method1)) # True
```